# Custom modal/sheet is behind in react native expo router stack screen that has a representation set to modal

Tags: react-native, mobile, expo, modal-dialog, expo-router

Im just learning react native and i used expo on top of it.

I have screen `create.js` that set the presentation on screen option to "modal", Now in this screen i have to use SELECT input for my form (i used tamagui, and tried also gluestack, and reactnative paper) but the item option is rendered behind the `create.js` screen. I try setting the select parent `zindex` to the highest value but still it render behind the `create.js` screen. I also use custom modal to create custom select but it also render behind the `create.js` which is set the stack screen option representation  to "modal"

Here is my _layout code for Stack.Screen:

```
<Stack.Screen
   name="create" // <--- this is the "create.js screen"
   options={{
      headerShown: false,
      presentation: 'modal',
                        
   }}
/>
```

Here is the screenshot of the actual problem: https://kargax-qat-bucket.s3.ap-southeast-1.amazonaws.com/drivers/J09BykLmqF6i1jWVkdovja73c75JEaUDgV0nO8bc.png

Answer (score 0):

from the looks of it you're using tamagui,

you should do the following. Import a PortalHost into the expo router screen. Name the host something (name prop). Import a PortalItem into the component with the Sheet and wrap the Sheet with it. Use the portal host name as the PortalItem hostName. Make sure you remove the modal prop on the Sheet.